# Sqlite Example From NewBoston Android Series : no such table peopleTable exist

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm newbie to android following newboston on YouTube I stucked here. 
I checked on SO a few similar questions like this, But could not found any solution to my problem.

Need help.
While checking on device, when I click on update button it gives an : error is :
No such table peopleTable exist.
on clicking view button it shows no data, but the SQLView UI that I have set.

HotOrNot class

```
package com.ss;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class HotOrNot {

    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "person_name";
    public static final String KEY_HOTNESS = "person_hotness";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "HotOrNotdb";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "peopleTable";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

    private DbHelper ourHelper;
    private final Context ourContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

    private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public DbHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

                db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " ( " + KEY_ROWID
                        + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,  AUTO_INCREMENT ," + KEY_NAME
                        + " TEXT NOT NULL  , " + KEY_HOTNESS + " TEXT NOT NULL");


        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
        }

    }

    public HotOrNot(Context context) {
        ourContext = context;
    }

    public HotOrNot open() throws Exception {
        ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
        ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;

    }

    public void close() {
        ourHelper.close();
    }

    // called after create method
    public long createEntry(String name, String hotness) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_NAME, name);
        cv.put(KEY_HOTNESS, hotness);

        return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);

    }

    public String getData() {
        String[] coloumns = new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_HOTNESS };
        Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, coloumns, null, null,
                null, null, null);
        String result = "";
        int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
        int iName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);
        int iHotness = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_HOTNESS);
        // getting data from the database
        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
            result = result + c.getString(iRow) + " " + c.getString(iName)
                    + " " + c.getString(iHotness) + " \n";
        }
        return result;
    }

    public String getName(long l) {
        try {
            String[] coloumns = new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_HOTNESS };
            Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, coloumns, KEY_ROWID
                    + " = " + l, null, null, null, null);
            if (c != null) {
                c.moveToFirst();
                String name = c.getString(1);
                return name;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
        return null;

    }

    public String getHotness(long l) {
        try {
            String[] coloumns = new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_HOTNESS };

            Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, coloumns, KEY_ROWID
                    + " = " + l, null, null, null, null);
            if (c != null) {
                c.moveToFirst();
                String hotness = c.getString(2);
                return hotness;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
        return null;

    }

    public void updateEntry(long lRow, String mName, String mHotness) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ContentValues cvUpdate = new ContentValues();
        cvUpdate.put(KEY_NAME,mName);
        cvUpdate.put(KEY_HOTNESS,mHotness);

        ourDatabase.update(DATABASE_TABLE, cvUpdate, KEY_ROWID +"=" +lRow, null);

    }

    public void deleteEntry(long lRow1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ourDatabase.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID +"=" +lRow1, null);

    }
}
```

SQLlite example class

```
package com.ss;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.ss.HotOrNot;

public class SqLiteExample extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    EditText sqlName, sqlHotness;
    Button sqlUpdate, sqlView;
    Button sqlModify, sqlGetInfo, sqlDelete;
    EditText sqlRow;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sqlliteexample);
        sqlName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
        sqlHotness = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etHotness);
        sqlUpdate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSqlUpdate);
        sqlView = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSqlOpenView);

        sqlUpdate.setOnClickListener(this);
        sqlView.setOnClickListener(this);

        sqlModify = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bModify);
        sqlGetInfo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bGetInfo);
        sqlDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bDeleteEntry);

        sqlRow = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etRow);
        sqlModify.setOnClickListener(this);
        sqlGetInfo.setOnClickListener(this);
        sqlDelete.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.bSqlOpenView:
            Intent i = new Intent("com.ss.SQLVIEW");
            startActivity(i);

            break;
        case R.id.bSqlUpdate:
            boolean didItWork = true;
            try {
                String name = sqlName.getText().toString();
                String hotness = sqlHotness.getText().toString();

                HotOrNot entry = new HotOrNot(SqLiteExample.this);
                entry.open();
                entry.createEntry(name, hotness);
                entry.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                        didItWork = false;
                        String error = e.toString();
                        Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                        d.setTitle("ERROR");
                        tv.setText(error);
                        d.setContentView(tv);
                        d.show();


            } finally {
                String name = sqlName.getText().toString();
                String hotness = sqlHotness.getText().toString();
                Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                d.setTitle("FINALY");
                d.setContentView(tv);
                d.show();
            }
            break;
        case R.id.bGetInfo:
            didItWork = true;
            try {
                String s = sqlRow.getText().toString();
                long l = Long.parseLong(s); // convert edit text to long
                HotOrNot hon = new HotOrNot(this);
                try {
                    hon.open();
                } catch (Exception e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                String returnedName = hon.getName(l);
                String returnedHotness = hon.getHotness(l);
                hon.close();
                sqlName.setText(returnedName);
                sqlHotness.setText(returnedHotness);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                d.setTitle("catch");
                tv.setText(e.toString());
                d.setContentView(tv);
                d.show();
            } finally {
                Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                d.setTitle("FINLAY 2");
                d.setContentView(tv);
                d.show();
            }
            break;
        case R.id.bModify:
            didItWork = true;
            try {
                String sRow = sqlRow.getText().toString();
                long lRow = Long.parseLong(sRow);
                String mName = sqlName.getText().toString();
                String mHotness = sqlHotness.getText().toString();

                HotOrNot ex = new HotOrNot(this);
                ex.open();
                ex.updateEntry(lRow, mName, mHotness);
                ex.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                didItWork = false;
                String error = e.toString();
                Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                d.setTitle("DONE");
                tv.setText(error);
                d.setContentView(tv);
                d.show();
                didItWork = true;
            } finally {
                Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                d.setTitle("DONE");
                d.setContentView(tv);
                d.show();
            }
            break;
        case R.id.bDeleteEntry:
            didItWork = true;
            try {
                String sRow1 = sqlRow.getText().toString();
                long lRow1 = Long.parseLong(sRow1);

                HotOrNot ex1 = new HotOrNot(this);
                ex1.open();
                ex1.deleteEntry(lRow1);
                ex1.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                didItWork = false;
                String error = e.toString();
                Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                d.setTitle("DONE");
                tv.setText(error);
                d.setContentView(tv);
                d.show();
                didItWork = true;
            } finally {
                Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                d.setTitle("DONE");
                d.setContentView(tv);
                d.show();
            }
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

SQLView class

```
package com.ss;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SQLView extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        try{
        setContentView(R.layout.sqlview);

        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSQLInfo);
        HotOrNot info = new HotOrNot(this);

            info.open();
            String data = info.getData();
            info.close();
            tv.setText(data);
        }
         catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            String error = e.toString();
            Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
            TextView t = new TextView(this);
            d.setTitle("ERROR");
            t.setText(error);
            d.setContentView(t);
            d.show();

        }

    }

}
```

SQLLite example xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/wallpaper"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Name" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvHotness"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hotness Scale 1 t0 10" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etHotness"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvAge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Age" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bSqlUpdate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Update Sql Lite Database" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bSqlOpenView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="View" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvRowId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Enter Row Id" 
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:textSize="20dp"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etRow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bGetInfo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Get Information" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bModify"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Edit Entry" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bDeleteEntry"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Delete Entry" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't close the table creation.
So, the table won't be created.

Here

```
+ " TEXT NOT NULL  , " + KEY_HOTNESS + " TEXT NOT NULL");
```

should be

```
+ " TEXT NOT NULL  , " + KEY_HOTNESS + " TEXT NOT NULL)");
```

Comment: Now try to increase the value of `private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;` Set it to 3, for instance.

Comment: It worked ..but would it work on device having db version lower ?

Comment: Yes. When you change the DB structure, you **must** change the DATABASE_VERSION constant, in order to make the `onUpgrade()` method fire.